# When is the product of a hermitian unitary and another unitary hermitian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra

I have a Hermitian unitary $\hat{H}$ and I want to know, if $\hat{U}$ is some other unitary, when is $\hat{H}\hat{U}$ a Hermitian unitary? Specifically, what are the conditions on $\hat{U}$?

I know that if $\hat{U}$ is Hermitian then as long as they commute this is true. 
Also that if they commute, as long as $\hat{U}$ is Hermitian this is also true.

So then does it have to be the case that they commute AND $\hat{U}$ is Hermitian?

Thanks a lot for the help in advance!

Comment: Perhaps this question would be more appropriate on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/)?  It's purely a math question.